# Adjusting the Active/Inactive state for a Trigger in the Developer Console

Tags: developer-console

I recently got [caught out using the Developer Console](https://twitter.com/FishOfPrey/status/872999527917076481) to edit a trigger where the active/inactive state had been changed after I opened it.

Every save from the Developer Console was restoring the trigger to the inactive state it was in when I opened it. Hilarity ensued.

So it would appear the Dev Console is carrying that metadata around about the active state.

In researching my problem I came across an [interesting post by Patrick Connelly](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000MJkQIAW) with the following screenshot:

[image]

Note the option in the Developer Console to toggle the active status from his screen shot versus mine:
[image]

**How can I get this checkbox to display in the Developer Console?**

Comment: Perhaps you've found a Bug?

Comment: @crmprogdev Maybe. I'm trying to recall ever seeing the Active checkbox in the developer console. It would certainly be a useful thing to have.

Comment: I can recall seeing it, but it was a long time ago and I believe it was in a sandbox, but it may have been a dev org. It was definitely not in a production org.