# Tooling API Inactivate Apex Trigger

Tags: apex, tooling-api

I am trying to inactive Apex Trigger using tooling API. I don't see any errors, I am getting "Success" message, but Trigger is not getting updated with inactive flag.

```
String json= '{ "MetadataContainerId":"1dcS0000000fGp7IAE", "ContentEntityId": "01qS0000000YCKZIA4", "Metadata": { "status": "Inactive"} }';
Httprequest req =new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/services/data/v43.0/tooling/sobjects/ApexTriggerMember/');
req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
req.setHeader('Authorization','OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setBody(json);
Http httpReq =new Http();
HttpResponse res = httpReq.send(req);
System.debug(res.getBody());
```

> System.HttpRequest[Endpoint=https://yearup--Staging.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v43.0/tooling/sobjects/ApexTriggerMember/,
>   Method=POST] System.HttpResponse[Status=Created, StatusCode=201]
>   DEBUG|{"id":"401S0000000ANl3IAG","success":true,"errors":[],"warnings":[]}

```
// Create a Trigger
String json = '{ "Name" : "AccountTrigger", "TableEnumOrId" : "Account", "Body" : "trigger AccountTrigger1 on Account (before insert) { for(Account objacc : trigger.new){}}" }';
Httprequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v27.0/sobjects/ApexTrigger');
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
req.setBody(json); 
Http httpReq = new Http();
HttpResponse res = httpReq.send(req);
System.debug(res.getBody());
// 01q54000000ShJ9AAK

// Create container
Httprequest req =new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/services/data/v28.0/tooling/sobjects/MetadataContainer/');
req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
req.setHeader('Authorization','OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setBody('{"Name":"TriggerMContainer"}');
Http httpReq =new Http();
HttpResponse res = httpReq.send(req);
System.debug(res.getBody());
// 1dc54000000bs2bAAA

// Update Trigger
Httprequest req =new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/services/data/v28.0/tooling/sobjects/ApexTriggerMember/');
req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
req.setHeader('Authorization','OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setBody('{"MetadataContainerId":"1dc54000000bs2bAAA","ContentEntityId" : "01q54000000ShJ9AAK", "Metadata": { "status": "Inactive"} }');
Http httpReq =new Http();
HttpResponse res = httpReq.send(req);
System.debug(res.getBody());


// Create Async
Httprequest req =new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/services/data/v28.0/tooling/sobjects/ContainerAsyncRequest/');
req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
req.setHeader('Authorization','OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setBody('{"MetadataContainerId" : "1dc54000000bs2bAAA", "isCheckOnly": "false"}');
Http httpReq =new Http();
HttpResponse res = httpReq.send(req);
System.debug(res.getBody());
// 1dr54000001zhB4AAI

// Async Status
Httprequest req =new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/services/data/v28.0/tooling/sobjects/ContainerAsyncRequest/1dr54000001zhB4AAI');
req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
req.setHeader('Authorization','OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
req.setMethod('GET');
Http httpReq =new Http();
HttpResponse res = httpReq.send(req);
System.debug(res.getBody());
```

**Error**:

[image]

Comment: Is the trigger part of a managed package?

Comment: I've had [issues historically with the Developer Console resetting the Active/Inactive Status on a trigger](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/178184/102). Since the Developer Console uses the REST API is _should_ be possible to replicate the same call.

Answer (score 0):

Your request to update the `ApexTriggerMember` of this `MetadataContainer` succeeds, but that doesn't actually perform a deployment - it stages it in the container. The `ApexTrigger` Tooling API object itself does not support [CRUD operations in an active org](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_crud_operations.htm).

From the Tooling API [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_metadatacontainer.htm),

> Use a MetadataContainer as a package for your tool’s workspace. As a user works in the tool, update the ApexClassMember, ApexTriggerMember, ApexPageMember and ApexComponentMember objects in the MetadataContainer and use a ContainerAsyncRequest object to save and deploy changes to the current organization.

You need to use a [`ContainerAsyncRequest`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_containerasyncrequest.htm) to request a deployment of your container (by supplying its Id in the `MetadataContainerId` field).

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to creating ContainerAsyncRequest, however, I keep getting deployment error as attached screenshot. do you think, we need to contact support or it just that I am missing anything here?

Comment: @Ajay Yeah, that's a gack. Nobody outside of Salesforce has the access to tell you exactly what it means.

Comment: this is what I received from salesforce, "Unfortunately, this behavior *is* WAD per the current design of the tooling API. Our Product team has confirmed that this is a document BUG and the document needs to be updated."

Comment: Oh interesting. Do you have a sense of what they're saying they'll update in the docs?

Comment: I am also surprised, they gave me the link and said that they will be updating this document. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_apextrigger.htm. Did you ever know about this?